# Why it does awk give me a fatal error : I/O?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am trying to execute below code in my script.
It is a small part of my code which is throwing an I/O error after successfully executing my script.

Is anything wrong with my usage of code. I dont need that error message to print it in my screen after my output.

```sh
 awk '/.edu  { sub(".edu",".edu")}}1' | sed 's/\.edu/.fail/g' < temp1.txt >> output.txt
```

Comment: Hi Beth, welcome to SO! Could you please edit your question and add a bit of context, e.g. what you are trying to achieve, how the desired output should look like?

Comment: I suggest you ask this question on [unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) which seems a better fit for shell related questions.

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that

```
awk '/.edu | .eda/{c++; if (c==2) { sub(".edu",".edu")}}1'
```

is doing what you expect ? It replaces `<any character>edu` by `.edu` on the second line where `<any characyer>eda` or `<any character>edu` appears.

Another error on that part : you don't provide any input to this awk command.

Then you redirect both content of temp1.txt and standard output of awk to sed (which is also weird)

```
awk ... | sed 's/\.edu/.fail/g' < temp1.txt
```

I guess that is why you get an I/O error.

If awk command is useful, just do :

```
awk '/.edu | .eda/{c++; if (c==2) { sub(".edu",".edu")}}{gsub("\.edu",".fail")}1' temp1.txt >> output.txt
```

If awk command is useless, do :

```
sed 's/\.edu/.fail/g' temp1.txt >> output.txt
```

---

> My requirement is : if in my input, i see .edu or .eda , replace it with .fail. if the line has both .eda & .edu replace only .edu with .fail keeping .eda as it is

Input example :

```
.eda
.edu .eda
.eda .edu
.edu
hello world
```

Code :

```
awk '!/\.edu/{gsub(/\.eda/,".fail")}{gsub(/\.edu/, ".fail")}1' test.txt >> output.txt
```

You'll get:

```
.fail
.fail .eda
.eda .fail
.fail
hello world
```

Comment: My requirement is : if in my input, i see .edu or .eda , replace it with .fail. if the  line has both .eda & .edu replace only .edu with .fail keeping .eda as it is

Comment: It is throwing me warning. Can u remove it.

Comment: Please do an effort @BethMckey. What warning, on which context ?

Comment: Ah, **that** would be the warning she was attributing to my script. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57376465/why-it-does-awk-give-me-a-fatal-error-i-o/57387056?noredirect=1#comment101310488_57387056. That's because you're using string (`"..."`) instead of regexp (`/.../`) delimiters around the regexps so awk has to first convert the string to a regexp and **that** is when that warning will occur since that process will strip the backslash.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks ! I didn't get any warning on my awk, good to know for portability. I edited

Comment: It's actually a good warning to get and one that should be acted on by either switching to RE delimiters or doubling up on the backslashes - you might want to upgrade your awk :-).

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
awk 'script' | sed 'script' < file
```

tells sed to expect it's input to come from the output of awk but then says "oh, no wait - take it from file instead". It also tells awk to run on no input so it'll hang waiting for you to type something. You probably meant to write this instead:

```
awk 'script' file | sed 'script'
```

so awk reads `file` and pipes it's output to sed. Having said that, you never need to pipe awk output to sed, you can just do whatever you want inside the original awk script. You wrote:

```
awk '/.edu | .eda/{c++; if (c==2) { sub(".edu",".edu")}}1' | sed 's/\.edu/.fail/g' < temp1.txt
```

and said in a comment that:

> My requirement is : if in my input, i see .edu or .eda , replace it with .fail. if the line has both .eda & .edu replace only .edu with .fail keeping .eda as it is

so this is probably what you really wanted (untested since you didn't provide any sample input/output to test against:

```
awk '!sub(/\.edu/,".fail"){sub(/\.eda/,".fail")}1' temp1.txt
```

Comment: Thank you its working for me. Please explain me the above usage of awk & help me resolving the warning produced in the output

Comment: @BethMckey What warning?

Comment: Awk: warning: escape sequence '\.' treated as plain '.'

Comment: That cannot happen with the awk script I posted since every `\.` is in a regular expression where it's necessary to use `\.` to avoid `.` being a regexp metachar. Please copy/paste my script again and retry. If you still get that message then please edit your question to show a copy/paste of your terminal where you're executing the script and the warning message you get.

Comment: It tries to replace ".edu" with "fail". If it can't then it tries to replace ".eda" with "fail". The `1` at the end is a common awk idiom to print the current line by specifying a true condition, it's equivalent to writing `{print $0}`.

Comment: Didn't think about using the return value of `sub`. Nice one

Comment: @BethMckey you should definitively accept this answer as it is the same as mine with better explanations & better code (better performance because it searchs edu only once)